# how to use keyup/keydown and select with autocomplete function in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, autocomplete

I am able to select the value using onclick function but i want to select the value using keyup/keydown also.i tried so many things but those are not working.What function i need to use when i have to reach to the correct value using keyup/keydown and select that value.

```
              $("#employer").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "employerNameAutoSuggestionList?ajax=true",
                            data: { employer: request.term },
                            success: function (result) {
                                var arr =result.data;
                                $("#suggesstion-box").empty();
                                $("#suggesstion-box").show();
                                if($("#employer").val() == "")
                                {
                                    $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
                                }
                                $("#suggesstion-box").append('<ul id ="empVal" style="list-style-type: none; display:inline" ></ul>');
                                var ul = document.getElementById("empVal");
                                 for (var i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++) {
                                   var li = document.createElement("li");
                                   li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));
                                   ul.appendChild(li);
                                   ul.onclick = function (li) {
                                        $("#employer").css("background","#FFF");
                                        $("#employer").val(li.target.innerText);
                                        $("#suggesstion-box").hide();

                                    }

                                }
                                arr = null;


                            },
                            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                alert(error.responseText);
                            }

                        });
                    }

                 });

            $("#employer").on({
                keyup: function () {
                    if ( $(this).val() == "" ) {
                        $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
                    }
                }
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the syntax. Sample below.

```
$("#employer").on("keyup", function () {
                    if ( $(this).val() == "" ) {
                        $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
                    }
});
```

Comment: This above code is working fine ,That is for suggestion box hiding when we don't have anything in text box but i wanted to add new function so that keyup/ keydown will work and i could select a particular value.

Comment: What I wanted you to check is the syntax of putting the 'keyup' event, and its callback method.